# Space after emoji on attributed string (IOS, Objective C)

Tags: ios, textview, space, emoji

So i have to use attributed string to have #tags and @'s highlighted for my UITextView.n But when ever i add an emoji and hit space after it, it acts as a tab(4 spaces). Does anyone know a solution to make sure that space is recognized correctly and does not create that much white space after emoji?

Answer (score 1):

I was solving a very similar problem when I encountered this issue. Here is my solution. Hopefully it helps in your case. Good luck!

```
let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
mutableAttributedText.removeAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedText.length))
…
textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
```

I was initializing `mutableAttributedText` with `textView.text` rather than `textView.attributedText` since I wanted to throw out the previous attributes & start with a fresh `String` upon receiving a `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification`. This works for 1-byte UTF-8 characters (i.e. ASCII characters), but poses a problem for multi-byte UTF-8 characters, specifically emoji. This bug resulted in `UITextView` rendering an extended whitespace for each `” “` (space) character trailing an emoji. Notably, the extended whitespace looks like a tab character, but the underlying `String` maintained the correct `” “` character.

By initializing `mutableAttributedText` with `textView.attributedText` then removing the relevant attributes, I overcame this bug while still being able to add attributes to a *fresh* `NSAttributedString`.